# Visualizing indivual tracks of animals using one color per animal in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, tracking

I imported a .csv file as a layer, containing ID of animals and their tracks (GPS coordinates, speed and more). I would like to be able to visualize the tracks of the different animals separately, by attributing a different color to each individual. I have close to 100 individuals scattered in 5 areas on a map. Note that I do not want to split the initial layer in several because I will run 'heatmaps' on the whole data set afterward.

I work on QGIS 3.10.

Comment: Official guide on symbology: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#basic-fa-classifying-nominal-data

Comment: Are you asking how to use categorized symbology?

Comment: If you want first to look at each animal as a separate identity, you could just set a filter on the input file then progressively change it. Filters work fine with .csv files. 100 is a lot of iterations through the filter but if you categorize them you will still have to change the display 100 times to look separately at each of them. Maybe there is a clever way to animate this but I don't have the skill set to suggest how.

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed categorized symbology but I did not know I was looking for that. Thanks.